# C++ cgi скачать файл

Tags: cgi, c++

Собственно сабж. Как это можно замутить?

Comment: @jaroslav, у Вас неправильное представление о телепатических способностях читателей форума.

Опишите толком, что Вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Мутят с помощью библиотеки cURL (легко гуглиться). Но если это не просто абстрактный с++, а  какой то конкретный, то можно использовать местные библиотеки (это может быть Qt или даже С++Builder c idny).

Comment: Средствами Qt как можно сделать?

Comment: вот [пример](http://contingencycoder.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/quick-tip-download-a-file-in-qt/). Целый класс для красивой работы.

Comment: Почему при следующей конструкции выкачивается сам cgi-шлюз

"Content-type: application/force-download\n\n";
"Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt");

Comment: Выкачивается шлюз? я честно не сильно понимаю, как это. Но телепатия подсказывает спросить, а браузером нормально все получается?

Comment: Есть каталог на localhost. В нем файлы. Нужно средствами Qt выкачать файл на hdd. Если послать браузеру строки (см. выше), то открывается окно сохранения файла, но самого file.exe (который обрабатывает запросы). А нужно файлы ну например txt.

Comment: "вот пример. Целый класс для красивой работы." как тогда правильно использовать? Я так понял достаточно передать в конструктор параметры откуда качать и куда? Файл типа выкачивается (просто создается в указанном месте) но инфы в нем нет.

Comment: извините, это за пределами моей телепатии.